# An approach to remove a listener when it is dispatched

Tags: actionscript-3

I find `addEventListener` method a bit limited. I would like to use another version of it, made by me. I would like to insert a parameter that will tell if a dispatched event can be auto removed, so it will avoid me have to write this in everywhere:

```
obj.addEventListener(Click, function onClick(e:Event):void {
    obj.removeEventListener(Click, onClick); // <--- I want to avoid this
});
```

Then:

```
obj.addEventListener(Click, function onClick(e:Event):void {
    // no need anymore.
}, true); // <--- see
```

What approach can I take in order to reach that?

Comment: that totally depends on when you want to remove the event. If you want to remove the event when it is dispatched once, you best do it like you do now. If it is just about removing events when cleaning up, you might want to look at the `useWeakReference` parameter

Comment: @Marijn: that paramater (useWeakReference) give me some headache once. I'm afraid of it.

Comment: read this:
http://gingerbinger.com/2010/07/actionscript-3-0-events-the-myth-of-useweakreference/

Comment: You could use Signals instead https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always **intercept** your `addEventListener` method call using **override** with **closures**:

```
    override public function addEventListener(type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean = false, priority:int = 0, useWeakReference:Boolean = false):void 
    {
        var self = this;
        var weakListener:Function = function(e) {
            self.removeEventListener(type, weakListener);
            listener(e);
        }
        super.addEventListener(type, weakListener, useCapture, priority, useWeakReference);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and fairly simple solution to allow for anonymous functions is the arguments.callee property

```
obj.addEventListener(Event.WHATEVER, function(e:Event)
{
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.WHATEVER, arguments.callee);
    //Do your stuff
}
```

This creates the event listener and listen function at the same time, in the remove listener, it uses arguments.callee the reference the called function, allowing it to remove itself.